Can you combine Arcanist's Counterspell Exploit with Dispel Magic
I was wondering if Dispel Magic can be used with Counterspell Exploit feature instead of same level / same level +1 spell slot in counterspelling attempt...
...in the same way it can already by used used with regular Counterspell feature instead of same spell in counterspelling attempt.
What I'm also interested in is whether using Greater Dispel Magic for Counterspell Exploit would give +4 bonus to check.

Dispel magic has no extra benefit for Counterspell Exploit
Counterspell Exploit says

By expending 1 point from her arcane reservoir, the arcanist can attempt to counter a spell as it is being cast. She must identify the spell being cast as normal. If she successfully does so, the arcanist can attempt to counter the spell as an immediate action and by expending an available arcanist spell slot of a level at least one higher than the level of the spell being cast. To counterspell, the arcanist must attempt a dispel check as if using dispel magic. If the spell being countered is one that the arcanist has prepared, she can instead expend an available arcanist spell slot of the same level

This ability only works for spells you have successfully identified, while the use of Dispel Magic during "normal" counterspelling says

You can usually use dispel magic to counterspell another spell being cast without needing to identify the spell being cast. Dispel magic doesn’t always work as a counterspell (see the spell description).

This is an entirely different situation. Other than during normal counterspelling, here you never cast dispel magic. And Counterspell Exploit does not have any clause that allows you to use a prepared Dispel Magic in place of another spell. The only way you can use a prepared dispel magic is to counter another dispel magic being cast, with a same spell level slot instead of a higher one. This works no different than it would as if we were discussing any other spell.
There is no special +4 bonus on the check from greater dispel magic
Because you are not casting dispel magic or greater dispel magic to counterspell, you instead are using the Counterspell Exploit feature, you gain no +4 bonus on your counterspelling attempt if you have greater dispel magic prepared.
Countespell Exploit says that you "must attempt a dispel check as if using dispel magic", so you make the check as if using dispel magic, no matter what spells you have prepared. You even do not need to have dispel magic or greater dispel magic prepared for this.
The only benefit that you get from prearing it in this context is that you could counterspell another greater dispel magic with a level 5 or 6 slot (depending on the class that cast the one you aim to counter, and whose spell level you need to match with your slot), instead of a level 6 or 7 or higher slot.

The text of the ability is

If the spell being countered is one that the arcanist has prepared, she can instead expend an available arcanist spell slot of the same level, and she receives a +5 bonus on the dispel check.

If you expend a dispel magic for this ability, you can either counter a dispel magic of the same level with a +5 bonus or any spell that is a lower level (as normal). There is no allowance for using dispel magic as a catch-all and it does not use the 'normal' counterspell rules.

I can't even tell if this answers my question or not. Most likely not. Please turn this into something more clear.

@NecXelos I think this says No, it won't work unless the spell happens to be dispel magic itself. I felt it was clear enough. I discarded my more wordy answer I had drafted and upvoted it when it was posted as I thought it  captures the core argument succinctly
